# Best practises in catching exception from wcf in winforms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf

I am currently doing some research on how to handle exceptions and let the client know in a winforms app which calls a WCF service (Self-hosted in a windows service). What is the best way for this? A couple of questions:

1) If I let an exception propagate, it'll come up on the client side.
2) What's the best way to catch the exception on the client side? Is it:

```
catch (FaultException<T> fault) { }
```

(Empty catch block just for demo purposes). Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put each of your calls in a try{}catch{} block since that is where it will be propagated from on the client side, possibly encompassing some of the possible exception handing in some sort of proxy to hide the WCF specific handling.
Using exception shielding you can also specify custom FaultExceptions and decorate the method with attributes to allow that exception to be sent down to the client. That way you can be a little more intelligent when the exception arises.
e.g.

```
    try{
       ... call service
    }catch(FaultException<TimeoutFault> ex){
       .. try one more time
    }catch(FaultException<InvalidSelection> ex){
      ... show message to user from ex.Details.InvalidProperty
    }catch(FaultException){
      ... handle
    }catch (CommunicationException ex){
       ... remember this is WCF so the call itself might fail
    }catch(Exception ex){
     ... handle        
    }
```

Id reccomend reading http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx as it has a few good tips/

Comment: Your `catch` block for `CommunicationException` is unreachable. You need to arrange your exceptions properly.

Comment: Should some/all of this catch stuff go in the global exception handler so it is handled in one place? If the WCF calls are asynchronous (and they probably should be for a desktop app) then just catch any exception, marshall it over to the UI thread and throw.

Comment: ha ha yes fair call matthew. looks like i need to pay more attention to my code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You should always at least catch [CommunicationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationexception.aspx), of which `FaultException` (and others) derives from. Generally you will only get `FaultException` during development of your service (set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to get better faults while debugging). `CommunicationException` can occur when the service is not running, among many other reasons. You may want to read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx) for more information about error handling in your WCF service.